# Subtracting Data differing only by dates in 1 table Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `COSTS` CONTAINING `PART_NO`, `ITEM_COSTS`, `COST_DATE`.

How can I subtract the costs from different dates?  This is basically waht I am wanting

```
Select PART_NO
, ITEM_COSTS 
WHERE COST_DATE = DATE_A
AND PART_NO = B
```

AND SUBTRACT FROM THAT

```
Select PART_NO
, ITEM_COSTS 
WHERE COST_DATE = DATE_B
AND PART_NO = B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.part_no,
       b.item_costs - a.item_costs as diff
FROM costs a 
  JOIN costs b ON a.part_no = b.part_no 
WHERE a.cost_date = date_a
  AND b.cost_date = date_b
```

Comment: Thanks.  That gave me just what I needed.  I'm a self taught newbie and rarely think of joins like that!!